# teamviewer 13 crashing on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: teamviewer, qt5

I am getting the crash in Teamviewer 13 as follows now i have followed uninstalling the software ,removing the configuration files but it still doesn't works any idea would really help.I have also tried to use teamviwer 12 but that also crashes

```
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer[0xcfdedd]
    /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer[0xd3cb5c]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f7a10636390]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f7a10290428]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f7a1029202a]
    /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5(+0x9b8de)[0x7f7a10be68de]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5(_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate25createPlatformIntegrationEv+0x13c9)[0x7f7a111aae99]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5(_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate4initEv+0xe81)[0x7f7a111acbc1]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(_ZN12QApplicationC2ERiPPci+0x3d)[0x7f7a118bdbcd]
    /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer[0x4cf7bd]
    /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer[0x4d012c]
    /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer[0x41f3f1]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f7a1027b830]
    /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer[0x4b6ab3]
```

Comment: FWIW:  I use Teamviewer 11 on 16.04 with no problems

Comment: Two months ago, on my Ubuntu 18.04, I had similar crashes (libpthread) with freshly installed Teamviewer 15.3.2682 and fixed them by uninstalling and installing a previously downloaded 14.2.8352. This morning *suddenly* ran into libpthread crashes with that version, and no amount of restarting would help. No recent changes to the system. Had to drive to the office :(

Answer (score 0):

This will show the libraries needed.

```
ldd /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer
```

Does your system lack any of these libraies? Not sure if there is any library compatibility issue.

Comment: It was working earlier but then stopped working so don't think that's the problem it

Comment: Same for me: it stops working all of a sudden, without any recent changes to the system and stays that way after reboots. Happened with 15.3.2682 and with 14.2.8352 on Ubuntu 18.04 as server.